# No space left on device - android

Tags: android

while run time am getting the following errors... I clean my project then after that too am getting the same error

```
[2011-04-10 05:33:31 - PersonalTask] ------------------------------
[2011-04-10 05:33:31 - PersonalTask] Android Launch!
[2011-04-10 05:33:31 - PersonalTask] adb is running normally.
[2011-04-10 05:33:31 - PersonalTask] Performing com.acarin.project.personal.task.LoginPage activity launch
[2011-04-10 05:33:31 - PersonalTask] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MA_AVD_2.3.1'
[2011-04-10 05:33:31 - PersonalTask] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MA_AVD_2.3.1'
[2011-04-10 05:33:34 - Emulator] NAND: could not write file D:\Bama_BackUp\andr\android-sdk-windows/platforms\android-9\images\/system.img, No space left on device
```

Any one can help me pls thank you fri

Comment: Did you check, that there is actually space left on Device d: ?

Comment: @theomega s 19GB free space on d: ..... thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The system NAND flash for the emulator has run out of space.  Your host system D: is not the issue, but for some reason the system.img file that represents a NAND flash for the emulator is full.  You can try creating a new emulator, or doing a factory default reset in the emulator to clean it up.  To do this, either issue a Factory Data Reset inside Android under Settings -> Privacy, or start the emulator from the command-line:

```
android list avd
emulator -avd My_Avd_Name -wipe-data
```

The first command list all Android Virtual Devices.  You need the name for the second command.  The emulator should not already be running.  A third option would be to delete the disk images located under your Windows profile.  Under your profiles, it's `.android/avd/My_Avd_Name.avd`  You should only need to delete `userdata-qemu.img` and maybe  `cache.img`.  You can try deleting other image files if necessarily, but note, `sdcard.img` won't be re-created automatically.  You need to run `mksdcard` from the command-line.

Comment: thank you ,will you tell me how to reset the emulator to clean

Comment: @ezhil Updated answer to include

Comment: I have been into this issue for too long while developing on Linux. Later on I realized that emulator also needs space in your / (root) as well as /home directory. When I cleared some space from / this issue was resolved for me.

But the error msg "NAND: could not write..." is really inappropriate.

Comment: I've done this a few times and it seems to work some of the time.

Comment: What if the device is a real device?

Answer (score 7):

This may also happen because, you dont have free space in the drive where you are creating your Emulator, try deleting few items of that drive and it would get launched, make sure you have 1 gb (for precautions) data free in the drive. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

1 - Eclipse IDE : you can set :

> run -> run configurations -> choose your run config -> Target ->Additional Emulator Command Line Options : -partition-size 512

2 - Console :

> android-sdk-home/tools> android list avd
>
> emulator.exe -avd  -partition-size 512 -no-snapshot-load

3 - You can also create new avd with enough space, since android apps install first in the phone partition (you can move it later to sdcard), you have to check in your phone

> Settings -> Sd cards & phone storage -> Internal Phone storage -> available space

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. If you have a MAC OS X. You might want to disable RamFS you created.
either:

```
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/StartupItems/RamFS
```

or:

```
sudo chmod -R 000 /System/Library/StartupItems/RamFS
```

The latter to disable it.

Don't forget to restart your MAC after completing one of the above steps.

Aparantly the SDK is giving misleading information on which mount the space is not enough...

You could also increase the size of the RamFS but how much RAM do you have?

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I my case it was not the problem with device and

> 'sudo rm -rf /tmp/*'

solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

**ADV** config now moved to Android Studio already.

###### 1. Open Device Manager from Android Studio

[image]

###### 2. Select device you want to change Disk Space.

- Click icon **Pen** at **Actions** column.
- Click **Show Advance Setting**
- Input **Internal Storage**
- Click **Finish**

[image]