# NAND error in Hello World project in the official Android developer tutorial

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm working on the Hello World project at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

The trouble comes when I run the application. The sequence of messages I get is something like:

```
[2012-04-30 15:13:19 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2012-04-30 15:13:19 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2012-04-30 15:13:19 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2012-04-30 15:13:19 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2012-04-30 15:13:19 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2012-04-30 15:13:19 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2012-04-30 15:13:25 - Emulator] NAND: could not write file /tmp/android-jhsu/emulator-7iTL7m, File exists
```

What exactly is stopping the process from executing properly? What do I need to do to fix this?

UPDATE 1:

OK, I tried your suggestions about clearing the avd.

I went into my android_sdk_linux directory and entered "tools/android list avd".  The output was:

```
Available Android Virtual Devices:
Name: my_avd
Path: /home/jhsu/.android/avd/my_avd.avd
Target: Android 4.0.3 (API level 15)
ABI: armeabi-v7a
Skin: WVGA800
```

So I entered "tools/emulator -avd my_avd -wipe-data".  The output was:

```
NAND: could not write file /tmp/android-jhsu/emulator-5FHEn7, File exists
```

But I looked in the /tmp/android-jhsu directory and saw no file at all, not even a hidden file.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Maybe your emulator disk image is out of space, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5605025/180740?

Comment: Just delete your emulator and create another one

Answer (score 8):

I was able to fix it exporting `ANDROID_TMP`

```
export ANDROID_TMP=/home/myuser
```

Answer (score 2):

For me at least, I'd let my disk run out of space without realizing it.

It was just coincidence that this was the first item that failed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a real disturbing situation when error can't completely describe problem in detail!
finally I figured out all this kind of error messages ("File Exists" and "There is no space") are due to small amount of mounted space on /tmp folder.
in Linux try `mount` and you'll see specified parameters of tmpfs and /tmp

changing $ANDROID_TMP value is not a proper solution and even doesn't work at all.

try editing **fstab**

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

and increase /tmp size to a larger value that makes sense to you (like:1500M)
then **reboot** system

*PS: It's not IDE-dependent (Eclipse or Android-Studio) but something that deal with AVD Emulator*