# Android emulator device not launching

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I try to launch the emulator its showing this error...though everything was working fine 2 days back..even

```
[2013-03-04 11:35:28 - h m s] Android Launch!
[2013-03-04 11:35:28 - h m s] a d b is running normally.
[2013-03-04 11:35:28 - h m s] Performing com.my.Intro activity launch
[2013-03-04 11:35:28 - h ms] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible A V D 'Mobile'
[2013-03-04 11:35:28 - h ms] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Mobile'
[2013-03-04 11:36:14 - Emulator] N AND: could not write file C:\`D O C U M E~1\R I TI K A~1.PAN\LOCALS~1\Temp\\A n d r o i d E m u l a t o r\TMP3E.t mp, No space left on device
```

Comment: Check these links : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332797/no-space-left-on-android-emulator

and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604951/no-space-left-on-device-android

Answer (score 1):

Close all emulators .

Open command prompt ,navigate to android sdk >tools > folder .And

type  following command .

emulator -avd **My_Avd_Name**.

Here **My_Avd_Name** is name of avd which you need to show(which already exist in our AVD manager list).

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
run -> run configurations -> choose your run config -> Target ->Additional Emulator Command Line Options : -partition-size 512
```

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse go to window->android virtual device manager-> edit the avd and increase the RAM size
Or If you are using any other IDE just Increase the RAM size of Emulator

Comment: Ram size is 700 mb as it cant be more than 768 mb on the system ...still the same error

Comment: It is the problem with space availability .. I hope you have some space on your hard drive too

Answer (score 0):

Create new avd in virtual manager and then try again. set ram size as 256 and then try again.
or in command prompt try this

```
      android list avd
    emulator -avd My_Avd_Name -wipe-data
```

or in eclipse
run -> run configurations -> choose your run config -> Target ->Additional Emulator Command Line Options : -partition-size 512

Comment: ok please delete all your avd and create new avd and then try again.

Comment: Android Launch!
[2013-03-04 13:08:10 - hms] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-04 13:08:10 - hms] Performing com.my.Intro activity launch
[2013-03-04 13:08:10 - hms] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Mobile' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2013-03-04 13:08:10 - hms] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'mobile'

Comment: [2013-03-04 13:08:35 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2013-03-04 13:08:35 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2013-03-04 13:08:35 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2013-03-04 13:08:35 - Emulator] 
[2013-03-04 13:08:35 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2013-03-04 13:08:35 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: sometimes eclipse have this problem. please update eclipse and goto sdk manager and update sdk tools and android sdk platform tools and then create new avd and try again:)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your C drive has some space left. Because clearly as per the trace,

> ***could not write file C:`D O C U M E~1\R I TI K A~1.PAN\LOCALS~1\Temp\A n d r o i d E m u l a t o r\TMP3E.t mp, No
>   space left on device***

So clean up some disk memory and try again.