# Android Studio 2.1 Preview1 Gives No space left on device Error

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated my android studio to 2.1 preview version, after that it's giving 
No space left on device Error.
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get rid of this error by **restarting Android studio/your system**.

To solve this issue, do not update your SDK directly from popup you get when there is any update available, instead
Goto -> **SDK Platforms** window,

or Goto **File->Settings->Appearance and Behavior->System Settings->Android SDK**

In that opened window you will see **Launch Standalone SDK Manager**

Click on that it will open another window,update your SDK from there.

Comment: worked ok for me, thanks. Also that native android sdk manager can be opened via Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> Launch Standalone SDK Manager

Comment: There is no longer a standalone SDK Manager. I'm using Android Studio on Windows and it mostly ignores vmoption `-Djava.io.tmpdir=d:\temp`

Answer (score 10):

For me, this was due to my **/tmp partition being too small**. I got these errors both when trying to install a large device image (Android 7.1) and when trying to start an AVD. It seems that Android Studio will try to unzip big files in /tmp.

To increase the size of /tmp on Linux, set the size= parameter in /etc/fstab, e.g. on my Ubuntu I now have:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,size=3g 0 0
```

A reboot is needed to apply that change.

Note that [tmpfs is entirely held in RAM](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/TmpOnTmpfs) so you should probably undo this change after the installation of these components.

Comment: I confirm that the issue seams to be the consequence of /tmp size. My development workstation is deployed on VM. So, I've got a simplicity to increase resources dedicated for the machine. Increasing RAM, and in consequence /tmp solved my problem too.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR**(This happens if there is no free space in `/tmp`)

*To increase the size of `/tmp` just type the below command in terminal*

`$ sudo mount -o remount,size=8G /tmp/`

**P.S.:-** *8G is an arbitary value, you can set it to any size as far as its enough to done the job.*

Answer (score 4):

You can also solve this by using  `TMPDIR=pathtodirectorytobeusedastmp` before launching studio.sh from terminal.

eg: `TMPDIR=/HOME/user/downloads studio.sh`

P.S. This only applies if you are using any of the linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

What device are we talking about here? Is this for your emulator?

If so, try the following methods:

1. Try clearing the cache on the device. Cache storage can take up some unneeded space, especially on an emulator device.
2. In a console window, type the following commands.

   android list avd

   emulator -avd My_Avd_Name -wipe-data

What this will do is wipe the data for the emulator you choose to clear.

3. Create a new virtual device, and allocate more space to it. I'm not sure if you can edit your existing one add just add more space to it or not.

Resources:

- [StackOverflow: No space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604951/no-space-left-on-device-android)
- [Android Emulator: No space left on device](https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/83431/android-emulator---no-space-left-on-device)

Comment: No it's not for emulator, i'm just building and syncing the project, it's giving this message

Comment: @SultanMirza what is the exact message that you get? Can you please add it in as an edit to your question? It can clarify some things and give a better direction. Thanks.